# How can I use a session variable in my default_scope call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app where my user logs in and they are associated with a given company.    I want to add a default scope to all my models so that the user only sees the data from their company.  So in my `Location` model I tried:

`default_scope where(:company_id => session[:company_id])`

Rather than littering these through my app.  My thought is to make it secure so that by default the `Location` queries always are restricted to the current users company_id.  All of my other models are somehow associated back to a `Location` so this should be the only place I need to do this.

I had some poking around and I got the idea that doing this was a bad idea (even though I could not see how you would actually do it).

Can I in fact do this and if so how?  Is there perhaps a better way around this?

Comment: Ive just been attempting the same thing, whatt logic did you come too ? or did you just remember to include / apply the session variable to all queries ?

Mortiz solution seems clean - be interested in any resolution you figured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing out old questions - for tenancy the best options are Apartment or acts_as_tenant.  I ended up settling recently on activerecord-multi-tenant as Apartment seems to have more and more issues with scaling.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to have a private method within your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :my_model

  def my_model
    Model.where(:company_id => session[:company_id])
  end

  ...
end
```

And then use it from within your concrete actions:

```
@models = my_model.where("created_at > ?", 2.weeks.ago)
```

`helper_method` makes sure that you can use the method as a helper from within views. I hope this gives you the general idea.